# Would it be possible to manufacture Quantumly entangled atoms for lets say a phone or some other type of communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

So lets say you have this wonderful machine that can entangle two atoms.Then you take atom A and you know how to make it spin clockwise and back counterclockwise and connect it to an 8 bit cable.Then you take atom B and put it in a phone instead of a wireless receiver, where the phone can read if its spinning clockwise or counterclockwise.Now when you search "how to bake a chicken" it takes that information spins the right atoms causing it to spin the ones at this big warehouse that process information and when it finds the information for the website your looking for , spins the atoms to transmit the information back to your phone meaning you have instantaneous and universe wide service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Generally speaking, faster-than-light communication leads to situations where it is possible to send messages into the past. A somewhat involved example is available on Wikipedia: [Tachionic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone) (and if that's not a cool name for a thought experiment, I don't know what is).

It seems like your idea comes from a misunderstanding of [Quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), and quantum mechanics in general. Consider the following example:

One blue ball and one red ball sit in a bin. You and your friend close your eyes, pull out a ball at random, and walk to separate rooms with your eyes still closed. These balls are now, kind of (only for the sake of analogy), entangled. You both now open your eyes. If you have the red ball, your friend must have the blue ball. You can't change the color of your ball to communicate at all with your friend. At its core, all quantum entanglement does is put these kinds of constraints on particles, as opposed to forming a quantum voodoo doll where whatever you do to one particle changes the other simultaneously (again, kind of).

Of course, this is oversimplified, and if things were this simple in real life we probably wouldn't even have a word for quantum entanglement. The intricacies arrive from the innate nature of how things are treated in quantum mechanics (or rather, simply how they *are* in quantum mechanics).

In the example I gave, the outcome was determined as soon as you reached into the bin and grabbed the red ball. To you, you had a 50/50 chance of grabbing the red ball. This probability stands until you open your eyes and see your ball is red. However, in reality, you always had the red ball, even if you didn't know it.

Quantum mechanics doesn't work this way. Let's say you and your friend grab a quantum ball out of the bin. There is no underlying hidden reality, and you can't say "the ball is red, even if you don't know it". The reality is, the ball itself is 50% red and 50% blue until you open your eyes and look at it. Now, let's say you go to your own rooms, but only you open your eyes. You see your ball is blue. Instantly, faster than any signal could go between the two rooms, your friends ball is now red despite never having been seen by human eyes. This is quantum entanglement. Neither ball was red or blue, then you looked at one, and instantaneously both balls decided on colors. How did your friend's ball know it had to pick a color, and how did it know it had to be red? That's the mystery. Likewise, you can't flip your balls color in an attempt to communicate with your friend.